# Python Jupyter Notebook Ipywidget Break a loop

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying, on Ipython notebook, to create graphs using plot.ly offline updated every ten seconds.

So I've put in an infinite loop a method creating and displaying the graph, wait for ten seconds with sleep, then clear_output()

I'm trying to control this infinite loop with a widget Interactive

```
def stopSeries(self, active):
    if (active == True):
        current_time = datetime.datetime.now(tzlocal()) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
        self.launchSeries(current_time.isoformat(), "", "", "", "", self.sensibility)
    time.sleep(self.delay)
    clear_output()
    self.on = active
    self.w.close()
    del self.w

def autoSeries(self, sensibility, delay):
    self.sensibility = sensibility
    self.delay = int(delay)
    while (self.on):
        self.w = interactive(self.stopSeries, active=self.on)
        display(self.w)

def autointeractSeries(self): 
    w = interactive(self.autoSeries, sensibility = FloatSlider(min=0,max=10,step=0.1,value=1), delay = "10", __manual=True)
    display(w)
```

Each 10 seconds, the check box fills again and the loop continue, I cant manage to break the loop, the self.on = active doesn't change self.on value